# Retrofit getMessage in onFailure returns null

Tags: android, api, retrofit2

I use these libraries in my app:

> implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
>
> implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
>
> implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'

It is my **RetrofitClientInstance** class implementations:

```
public class RetrofitClientInstance {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "my basic url";

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

Until this morning it was no problem but from this morning it is not working and **getMessage** in **onFailure** returns null and t.toString() returns java.net.SocketTimeoutException. (It is Ok on postman still).

```
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<Ad>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {

    call.clone().enqueue(this);
    Log.e("error in SplashScreen", "!!" + t.getMessage());
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: check your url is it working hit the url on browser and check result

Comment: It is Ok on postman.

Comment: check your pojo or JSON array or object

Comment: Try using t.getLocalizedMessage();

Comment: It is null too. When I changed timeouts to 60 it is Ok but very slow.

Comment: Then its probably because server takes more than 30 seconds to retrieve response. Keep 60 sec or more and check. .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

Comment: How can I increase API response speed from server?

Comment: just return t.toString(); ................. t.getMessage can return null.

Comment: You need to [edit] the question to post some additional information. 1) Which server you're using local or live server? 2) Post error log here. 3) Use `Log.e("log", "onFailure: ", t);` to log the error.

Answer (score 1):

From the [javadoc](http://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/) for retrofit

> `onFailure(Call<T> call, Throwable t)`
>
> Invoked when a network exception occurred talking to the server or when an unexpected exception occurred creating the request or processing the response.

If your specific request is okay on POSTMAN, then there is no chance that it could be going on the `onFailure()` callback unless:

1. The android client is not connected to the Internet.
2. The Base URL or the endpoint is wrong.
3. You are calling for a resource ie. `List<Ad>`that the endpoint cannot return.
4. Your Request type (`POST/GET/PUT/..`) is wrong.
5. The response is not available within the default timeout declared in the api client. code: `new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS) //connect timeout`

In addition to that I only do the following in my `onFailure()` callback and it works like a charm:

```
Log.e(TAG, t.getLocalizedMessage());
Log.e(TAG, t.getMessage());
t.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: When I set the timeout to 60 seconds it works correctly. So the problem is not number 1, 2, 3 and 4. Both t.getLocalizedMessage() and t.getMessage() returns null and t.toString() returns java.net.SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: @behrooz.fard Oh yes, that one is also one of the cases. If the network connection is low and the timeout second in default. I'll add that to my answer. Developing network related app for android is a tricky business, we should always aim for low bandwidth usage and target low speed connection.